# Increasing Block Size

Tags: block-production, block-size

a question about block limit, the amount of bytes that can be stored in each block. From what i can gather this value can be changed [Here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/d6f219c653f05aeb0663aaa05c9d6d62f93d00e4/runtime/src/lib.rs#L142), However when i change the 5 to lets say 20 (5mb to 20mb) I still get (Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits) error at the same amount of transactions. Just for clarification I am using the utility pallet for batching these transactions. So im guessing there is something else that must be done to increase block size!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You not only need to allow the block to get bigger, you also need to allow a higher `BlockWeights`. The `BlockWeights` is a parameter given to the `frame_system::Config` trait. It defines the amount of weight you allow per transaction type. If you don't increase that, you will not be able to push more transactions per block.

Comment: is there any examples on higher BlockWeights?